# find comments in javascript and css in python requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to find all the comments in the JavaScript and CSS pages. This code finds the HTML comments in HTML pages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from bs4 import Comment

with requests.session() as r:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0'}
    r = requests.get('https://example.com/page.js', verify=False, headers=headers)
    response = r.text
    soup = BS(response, 'html.parser')
    comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

    for c in comments:
        print(c)
```

But for JavaScript and CSS, the comments are between /* and */. Is there any way I can modify that code to retrieve JavaScript or CSS comments.

Comment: Sample data or that page's link could be help

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar enough with BeautifulSoup , but you can find where comments are, using `response.find('/*')`, `response.find('*/')` in a loop, using `find`'s second parameter, to start looking for the next comment, only after the end of the previous one.

disclaimer: you can still have /* or */ as text rather than a comment, this one is trickier to cope.